# Move file to directory

Tags: php, rename, move

So with your help I have been able to assemble the below.

```
$dir = "./reporting/live-metrics/";
$des = "./reporting/historic-metrics/";
$ctime = time(); 

foreach (glob($dir."*") as $file) {

$live = file_get_contents($file);

if (strpos($live, 'CORO') === false && filemtime($file) < time() - 1 * 10) {
$exclude[] = $live;
$lines = file( $file , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
$lines[3] = 'Taken Down';
$lines[5] = $ctime;
file_put_contents( $file , implode( "\n", $lines ) );
if (!file_exists($des.basename($file).PHP_EOL)) {
mkdir($des.basename($file), 0777, true);
}
rename($file,$des.$ctime);
}
}
```

My issue is that I am attempting to move the file to the new directory created but I am having a little issue with it. No matter what I do I can only get it to move to $des, i cant seem to get ti to move to the dynamicaly created directory for each specific file. I am assuming it has to do with the fact I am not using rename to its correct params. Below are the some of the combinations I have tried to get it to rename and move.

```
rename($file,$des.basename($file).PHP_EOL.$ctime); //doesn't move or rename
rename($file,$des.basename($file).$ctime); //adds to historic-metrics/ as jason1465519298
```

I also tried creating a function and setting the rename to call on that. eg.

```
$path = $des.basename($file).PHP_EOL;
rename($file,$path.$ctime);
```

Currently the script is great up until the moving the file. It will move it to ./reporting/historic-metrics/ but I would like it to move to the directory just created. EG, if the file it is currently handeling is called 'Jason' then it will create ./reporting/historic-metrics/Jason but move the file to ./reporting/historic-metrics/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. My main issue was trying to get the filepath to send the file to. After a few interruptions and rethinking my approach I came up with the below. I know it isn't pretty or as slim as could be made but it does the job perfectly.

```
$dir = "./reporting/live-metrics/";
$des = "./reporting/historic-metrics/";
$ctime = time(); 

foreach (glob($dir."*") as $file) {

$live = file_get_contents($file);

if (strpos($live, 'CORO') === false && filemtime($file) < time() - 1 * 10) {
    $exclude[] = $live; 
    $lines = file( $file , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
    $lines[3] = 'Taken Down'; 
    $lines[5] = $ctime; 
    file_put_contents( $file , implode( "\n", $lines ) ); 
    if (!file_exists($des.basename($file).PHP_EOL)) { 
    mkdir($des.basename($file), 0777, true);
}
$user = basename($file); //Gets file name that was used in mkdir
$path = (String) $des.$user."/"; //Compiles variables into string
    rename($file,$path.$ctime);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two possibilities:

1. Source or destination file paths may be wrong, you can print and check
2. The newly created destination directory is getting the
   correct permission & ownership.

Otherwise your script looks OK.

Comment: EDIT: Source file is fine. It will move the file to the following destination ./reporting/historic-metrics/. I use mkdir to make a folder inside this eg ./reporting/historic-metrics/Jason based on the file it is handeling. I am attempting to move the file into this Jason folder within the destination. The issue I have is that the destination folder inside $des is dynamic and changing based on the file it is handeling.

Comment: And permission and ownership too ?

Comment: Updated original with an image and hopefully a better explanation.

Comment: Hmm then I think next we can check the error logs or you can enable showing errors ini_set('display_errors', 1) on page itself. Or if you can run the script using command line, it should display the error on console.

Comment: Page already has the ini_set but no errors are displayed or located in log file. The script works fine but it is not moving to the directory I would like. I can get it to $des but not the new directory created by the mkdir.